# How can I read the contents of a crd file as plain text (i.e., recover my passwords)?

Tags: encryption, hashing, windows, decryption

I lost all my passwords due to a dumb mistake I did yesterday. These passwords are really important. My computer has them saved under Windows credentials. However, I can't view passwords stored under Windows credentials. When backing up the credentials I get a crd file. How do I view the passwords? I tried using Vaultpasswordview and credentialfileview but neither worked. I tried using John the Ripper but it didn't work (probably because I don't know how to use it). (I have experience in Python, if it helps.)

With Vaultpasswordview I was able to view the web credentials but not the Windows credentials. The hex on Vaultpasswordview is the password separated by dots while it's gibberish on Credentialfileview

I got the passwords of the vault without using any programs using the PowerShell with this code:

```
[void][Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
$vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault
$vault.RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword();$_ }
```

Can I change it to give me the Windows credentials instead of the web credentials?

Comment: How did you back up the windows creds?

Comment: Your answer "Windows gives you the option to back the credentials up." does not really answer the question "How did you back up the windows creds?". … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.